# Access denied for enabled xp_cmdshell for the admin user 

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, permissions, xp-cmdshell

I'm using xp_cmdshell within a database trigger to launch a exe file.

xp_cmdshell is enabled(it can execute simple cmd command like 'echo'). But when I try to launch the exe through xp_cmdshell, the access is denied.

I am the database administrator. And I can launch the exe through cmd directly. Anyone know why I get denied and how to fix it?

Comment: What exact error message do you get?

Comment: The message has no more details than that? It doesn't indicate whether it is talking about access to the stored procedure or the file system?

Comment: Just that. The stored procedure works and output the error message of the file system I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Likely insufficient NTFS permissions.   Make sure the 'user account' that the SQL Server is running as, has permission (Read+Execute) to the *.EXE (and any dependent files)

Comment: I am testing on my own db. And the exe is created by myself. I do have the permission to read and execute.

Comment: @JoshuaH. You have, but does the user that runs SQL Server (e.g. LocalSystem or NetworkService)?

Comment: +1 JMC. I agree that it sounds like the service account that the MSSQLServer service is running as doesn't have permission. Open services and check the login property for the SQL Server service account.

Comment: Login property: Server type:Data Engine, Authentication: Windows Authentication. How do i check whether user account has permission for the exe?

Comment: I've also have a question, as my SQL Server is running under Local System and still can't overdo this error.

Answer (score 14):

Use xp_cmdshell to run "whoami", then check effective permissions for the stated user on the exe and any resources it accesses.
Odds are that an account like localsystem is being used to run processes via xp_cmdshell.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'whoami'
```

Comment: I am getting this error. "whoami is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sorry, you might have to install it first, link here: http://serverfault.com/a/9984

Comment: I have installed the tool. whoami works fine when i executed it in cmd. But it failed in xp_cmdshell('whoami' is not recognized as an internal or external command). Do you know why this happend?

Comment: Weird.. you could try comparing the results of: "set comspec" & "set path" between cmd and xp_cmdshell, and make doubly sure you're connecting to a local server (turn off your local server and try to connect, should fail).

Comment: It tells it's nt service \ mssqlserver. Who should it be? That's the one that doesn't let me do anything.

Comment: @soulblazer if you have an account that you know works you can [set xp_cmdshell to run using it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql) just be aware of any security impact

Comment: @PeterWishart I set it to local system, and it finally allowed me to access my username folder. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I believe that the trigger is run by the user running the SQL command that "triggered" the trigger.

Is the user issuing the SQL command a Windows user or a SQL user ?  If it's a SQL user, you need to set an "SQL Proxy".  The SQL Proxy is used to tell SQL which Windows user will be used to access the file system.

Hope this helps,

Yves

Answer (score 0):

I was getting ACCESS DENIED when trying to run BCP and then COPY.

What I found is that xp_cmdshell starts in c:\windows\system32

I modified my CMD file to change to my working folder

L:
cd L:\myworkingfolder

This solved my problem, Event though my sqlagent was a local administrator and I had full pathed my copy command.

Answer (score 0):

Time to contribute now. I am sysadmin role and worked on getting two public access users to execute xp_cmdshell. I am able to execute xp_cmdshell but not the two users.

I did the following steps:

1. create new role:

   use master
   CREATE ROLE [CmdShell_Executor] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
   GRANT EXEC ON xp_cmdshell TO [CmdShell_Executor]
2. add users in master database: Security --> Users. Membership checks only [CmdShell_Executor] that is just created
3. set up proxy account:

   EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'domain\user1','users1 Windows password'
   EXEC sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'domain\user2','users2 Windows password'

Then both users can execute the stored procedure that contains xp_cmdshell invoking a R script run. I let the users to type in the password, execute the one line code, then delete the password. All in my pc.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get `Access is denied.` when you don't specify path to executable correctly. Note if your path contains spaces, you need to enclose the executable into double quotes:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell '"D:\My path\With spaces\runme.exe"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. Select your instance and right-click -> properties
3. Select Log on tab
4. And select authorized account